Restricting WebAuthn to specific YubiKeys in Keycloak
I am currently setting up WebAuthn for a service similar to Rancher using Keycloak. I have successfully configured WebAuthn and it is working as expected. To further enhance security, I have whitelisted specific AAGUIDs to enable only YubiKeys.
Now, I want to ensure that the YubiKeys used are only those that have been configured by myself, not just any randomly purchased YubiKey. The idea is to restrict the use of YubiKeys to the ones I have distributed to my team members, rather than allowing any YubiKey to be registered.
I am unsure if this behavior makes sense within the context of WebAuthn, or if it is even possible. If it is indeed feasible, could someone guide me on how to achieve this?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

I think there are two options:

Disable self-registration and register credentials on each yubikey before handing them out to your team
Use enterprise attestation, which means the YubiKey’s serial number becomes part of the attestation certificate.

The latter option is however only available on customized YubiKeys, as the origins for which EA is available must be preconfigured.

Thanks for your reply, I will try the enterprise attestation !

Reading to the documentation you linked, the enterprise attestation looks to be the good solution for my problem. But I can't find any user guide on how to setup all the yubikeys and the Keycloak server ? It look like I'm the only one that want to implement this feature
